# Find Resource path text file stream reader?

Tags: vb.net

How can I find a path in `Resource` (`words.txt`) in project, before `textfile` is saved in bin>debug, but now is saved in Resource and problem to reader in `Streamreader`?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("words.txt")
          Do While (True)
               Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
               If line Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
               End If
               Dim words As String() = line.Split("/")
               Dim word As String
               For Each word In words
                   If word = TextBox1.Text Then
                        TextBox2.Text = words(+1)
                   End If
               Next
          Loop
    End Using
End Sub
```